# would this combo of MAs be well rounded or no?

Tags: krav-maga, jeet-kune-do, systema

What arts are the best complements to KM? Also, how do other combat systems like Systema complement Krav compared to most normal MAs?

Comment: As it currently stands, this question invites opinions and discussions. It cannot have a "best" answer as there are too many factors.  What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: would other combative systems like systema, JKD, etc add in various elements i.e. range that weren't in Krav

Comment: Even when you turn the question around and ask *What does Krav Maga lack that other arts have?* it is still a poor question because there is no one definitive answer and it will attract plenty of opinion.

Comment: Yes!! All the MAs have their own combat styles, defensive and offensive strategies, etc... So learning more than 1 MA will definitely add more knowledge and experience to your MA knowledge. And fyi, it hasn't been mentioned anywhere that knowing KM would make you an unbeatable Martial Artist. And as @Sardathrion has mentioned, this can have so many arguable opinions, so an accurate answer cannot be provided.

Comment: @slugster Saying that one can't ask what arts complement a given art is a bit ridiculous to me. "What is a good complement to boxing" is a fine question.

Comment: I agree that it's unclear what is being asked, and why. The OP doesn't appear to know KM and is just being speculative. However, "what does Krav lack for purposes of X" is a perfectly answerable question.

Comment: I understand that you're keen to get this question reopened, but it really is way too broad in it's current form - in the space of four questions you're basically asking for a full dissertation on the strengths and weaknesses of Krav vs. other arts. Questions have to be specific and reasonably answerable, and there really should be one question, not several. Remember that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so try and tailor your questions that way.